# Staircase Ramp Function

Tags: functions

How is a linear ramp StairCase Function defined with given uniform $n$ steps in domain? The Floor function forces a unit increment on the x or t independent variable, so not suitable. Thanks.

EDIT

After the below and @Kubs's comment it is seen to work, but I mistook  earlier about inaccuracy from its plot, but it is ok in the Table.

```
xm = 2 Pi; dx = Pi/4.; Plot[Floor[x, dx]/xm, {x, 0, xm}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
i = 0; Table[{i++, x, Floor[x, dx]/xm}, {x, 0, xm, dx}] // TableForm
```

Comment: Can't you rescale `x`?

Comment: Can you give some minimal example what the function should produce? This makes it easier for people to reason about the problem and come up with ideas for a solution.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, It works. Actually I thought it does not give $1$ on $y$ in the staircase plot.

Comment: `ListStepPlot[Table[{n*Pi/4, n/8}, {n, 0, 7}], Joined -> False, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work:

```
NN = 7;
xmax = 20;
Plot[Floor[NN/xmax*x], {x, 0, xmax}]
```

With NN the number of steps and xmax the end of the domain.

[image]

Comment: Your solution gives out in xmax 6 instead of 1. You should normalize it!

Answer (score 1):

Is it this you are looking for?

```
Staircase[n_, x0_] := Sum[HeavisideTheta[x - (i/n) x0], {i, 0, n}]/n
Plot[Staircase[5, 1], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

With 12 steps, it would be:

Plot[Staircase[12, 1], {x, 0, 1}]

[image]